# How do I resize JScrollPane after resizing a JTextArea

Tags: java, swing, jframe

My JFrame Consists of three main parts a banner at top scrollpane containing a JTextArea center and a JTextField at the bottom. When I re-size the frame I adjust the columns and rows in my JTextArea. When making the frame larger the JTextArea expands visually but removes the scroll-bar. Then if I make the frame smaller the JTextArea stays the same size. This Is where I attempt to re-size my JTextArea.

```
    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {//Waits for window to be resized by user
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            uneditTextArea.setRows(((int)((frame.getHeight()-140)/18.8)));//sets Textarea size based on window size
            uneditTextArea.setColumns(((int)((frame.getWidth()-100)/10.8)));
            frame.revalidate();//refreshes screen

            }
        });
```

Why would the ScrollPane not re adjust to the change in size of the TextField.
The Rest of the code is below in case it is needed.

```
  public class window extends JFrame  
 {      
  private static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Lillian");      
  private static JButton inputButton = new JButton("Send");
  private static JTextField editTextArea = new JTextField(46);
  private static JTextArea uneditTextArea = new JTextArea(26,50);


  private static JPanel logoPanel = new JPanel();//Input text window
  private static JPanel itextPanel = new JPanel();//Input text window
  private static JPanel submitPanel = new JPanel();//Submit Button
  private static JPanel bottom = new JPanel();//will contain scrollpane
  private static JPanel middle = new JPanel();//willcontain itextpanel & submitbutton
  private static JPanel otextPanel = new JPanel();//Text Output
public static void runWindow() 
   { 
    ImageIcon logo = new ImageIcon("Lillian_resize.png");//banner
    ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("Lillian_icon.png");//application icon

    frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
    frame.setSize(660,640);
    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);    
    frame.setVisible(true);

    logoPanel.setSize(10,10);
    JLabel logoLabel = new JLabel(logo);

    final JScrollPane  scrollPane = new JScrollPane(otextPanel);//adds text to panel will scrollbar    
    scrollPane.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);//scrollbar only apears when more text than screen      
    scrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);//scrollbar never apears 
    scrollPane.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder());    

    logoPanel.add(logoLabel);
    submitPanel.add(inputButton);
    itextPanel.add(editTextArea);
    otextPanel.add(uneditTextArea); 

    frame.getContentPane().add(logoPanel,"North");
    frame.getContentPane().add(middle);
    frame.getContentPane().add(bottom,"South");

    middle.add(scrollPane,"North");//adds panels to outer panel
    bottom.add(itextPanel, "West");
    bottom.add(submitPanel, "East");

    uneditTextArea.setLineWrap(true);
    uneditTextArea.setWrapStyleWord(true);          
    uneditTextArea.setEditable(false);
    uneditTextArea.setCaretPosition(uneditTextArea.getDocument().getLength());

    frame.revalidate();//refreshes screen
//---------------wait for action------------

    frame.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {//Waits for window to be resized by user
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent e) {
            uneditTextArea.setRows(((int)((frame.getHeight()-140)/18.8)));//sets Textarea size based on window size
            uneditTextArea.setColumns(((int)((frame.getWidth()-100)/10.8)));
            frame.revalidate();//refreshes screen

            }
        });

   }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be no need to use a ComponentListener to resize components. That is the job of the layout managers that you use to dynamically resize the components.

You should not be adding the text area to a JPanel first. Instead when using text areas you would generally add the text area directly to the viewport of a JScrollPane by using code like:

```
JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane( textArea );
```

Then you add the scrollpane to the frame with code like:

```
frame.add(scrollPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
```

As you have noticed you should also NOT use hardcoded literals like "Center". Instead use the variables provided by the layout manager. Since you are using a BorderLayout, use the variables defined in the BorderLayout class.

Also, you should NOT be using static variable to create your GUI. I suggest you read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Layout Manager](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/visual.html). The tutorial will give you more information and the example code will show you how to better structure your program so that you don't need to use static variables.

Comment: Thank you the problem was that I wasn't adding the textArea to the scrollPane viewport, not really sure why I did that.